# Search results are duplicated after update_index (django haystack+whoosh)

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I use django-haystack with whoosh as a backend. I call **update_index** command in a scheduled intervals and I've noticed that after each update my search results contains a lot of duplicated entries (eg. after 3 update_index calls I have 3 duplicates of the same model instance).

HAve you faced this problem? Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to some bugs in whoosh.
According to Whoosh author it is fixed now: https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/issue/97/search-index-contains-a-lot-of-duplicates

Comment: Repository not found